# gnome-terminal: how to eliminate the scrollbar programatically?

Tags: x11, gnome-terminal

I'm spawning some processes running in their own gnome-terminal and
don't want to show the scrollbar.  Is there something like `xterm +sb`
to turn the scrollbar off for that particular window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Start gnome-terminal, select Edit->Profiles in the menu. Create a new profile and call it 'NoScrollbar'. In the profile preferences, go to the Scrolling tab, then set the scrollbar to 'Disabled'. To start a new terminal with the new profile, run the following command:

```
$ gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NoScrollbar
```

Comment: Thanks Lars, this is perfect.  On my version, it looks like it's called --window-with-profile, so I've updated your text.  Are there versions with just --profile?

Comment: I'm using version 2.26.0 under Ubuntu 9.04, and they both work here. I believe the difference is that --profile applies to all windows, while --window-with-profile applies to that window only. Which means that if you use your version and spawn a new window from the one you created, you will get the default profile again on the newly spawned window. You will have to decide what's more appropriate in your situation.

Comment: Google found this for me, but I have a question: is there any way I can disable scrollbar in gnome-terminal only when i'm using VIM?